# Selecting elements with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There is the set of potential facilities that we consider to build:

$\{H_i|1\leq i\leq m\} \cup$

$\{V_j|1\leq j\leq m\} \cup$

$\{D_{ij}|1\leq i,j\leq m\}$

Due to certain geographic constraints, there are several facilities that cannot be built together:

- For every $k$, facility $H_k$ cannot be built with $V_k$ (i.e. at most one of them can be built).
- For every $i,j$, facility $D_{ij}$ cannot be built with the following:

  - $H_{i-1}$, $H_i$
  - $V_{j-1}$, $V_j$
  - $D_{kl}$,  where $k \geq i$ and $l \leq j\ \ \ \ $ (except when $k=i$ and $l=j$, of course)
  - $D_{kl}$,  where $k \leq i$ and $l \geq j$

What is the largest number of facilities that we can build?

NOTES:

- If we consider only the $H$'s and the $V$'s, then it is obvious that the maximum number of facilities is $m$.
- The total number of $D$'s is also at most $m$.
- Therefore, the answer must be in the range ${m,...,2m}$.
- If we build $D_{ij}$, then we can build $D_{kl}$ only if $i<k$ and $j<l$, or $i>k$ and $j>l$.

EDIT: Let $m=2k$. We can select the following set:

$\{H_{(i)}|1\leq i\leq k\} \cup$

$\{V_{(j)}|k+1\leq j\leq 2k\} \cup$

$\{D_{(j+k)(j)}|2\leq j\leq k\}$

This set contains $3k-1 = \frac{3}{2}m-2$ facilities. This seems like the best possible, although I have no proof.

RELATED QUESTION:

- Is there a general name for this kind of questions?

Comment: One simple observation: turning every $V_i$ into $H_i$ in a valid solution gives a valid solution with the same amount of facilities, and without using any $V_i$. So the problem can be simplified by not menitioning them in the first place.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What if we have $H_1$, $V_2$, $D_{34}$? This is a valid solution, but turning $V_2$ to $H_2$ will make it invalid.

Comment: OK, I see I missed that $D_{i,j}$ does not exclude $V_i$, though it excludes $H_i$ and $V_j$. So my previous comment was misplaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems obvious that one cannot build more than $m$ facilities: for every $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ there is at most an $H_i$ or a $D_{i,j}$ for *some* index $j$; these possibilities are all mutually exclusive. And as mentioned in the question $m$ facilities is attainable.

*Edit*. Now that I see that $D_{i,j}$ does not exclude $V_i$, it seems that one can indeed do better than $m$. For instance with $m=7$, having $D_{1,5},D_{2,6},D_{3,7},$ is compatible with having in addition $H_4,H_5,H_6,H_7,V_1,V_2,V_3$; a total of $10$. Similarly one can get $m+\lfloor \frac{m-1}2\rfloor$ facilities in general by choosing $D_{i,i+m-d}$ for $i=1,\ldots,d$ where $d=\lfloor \frac m2\rfloor$, as well as $H_{d+1},\ldots,H_m$ and $V_1,\ldots,V_{m-d-1}$ (the final index is $\lceil \frac m2\rceil-1=\lfloor \frac{m-1}2\rfloor$). I think that is the best one can get.

Comment: This indeed seems the best one can get. But can you prove it? I tried but didn't find a proof..